# Scientific Linux 7.6 Grub Bootup menu not showing Windows 10 partition

Tags: grub, bootloader, scientific-linux

Looking for some help...

I have a dual boot Dell laptop that has functioned as a dual boot in the past with same software.

I had a bug and had to reinstall all last summer, but efforts to recreate have been unsuccessful.Currently my Scientific Linux 7.6 works fine, but I can't access my windows 10 partition.

A simple df command does not see the partition, os-prober doesn't seem to do anything. I can see the windows partitions with the fdisk-l command.

Grub bootup menu does not show windows option. I realize it is probably something to do with my Grub.conf file, but not sure what to change,add, or delete.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "reainstall all" since it sounds like you have kept your windows 10 install. The bootloaders can be particular if the proper procedures aren't followed.